# How to add multiple body params with fileupload in FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postman, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a machine learning model deployed using FastAPI, but the issue is I need the model to take two-body parameters

```
app = FastAPI()

class Inputs(BaseModel):
    industry: str = None
    file: UploadFile = File(...)

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(inputs: Inputs):
    # params
    industry = inputs.industry
    file = inputs.file
    ### some code ###
    return predicted value
```

When I tried to send the input parameters I am getting an error in postman, please see the pic below,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FastAPI discussion [thread--(#657)](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/657)

> if you are receiving JSON data, with `application/json`, use normal Pydantic models.
>
> This would be the most common way to communicate with an API.
>
> If you are receiving a raw file, e.g. a picture or PDF file to store it in the server, then use `UploadFile`, it will be sent as form data (`multipart/form-data`).
>
> If you need to receive some type of structured content that is not JSON but you want to validate in some way, for example, an Excel file, you would still have to upload it using `UploadFile` and do all the necessary validations in your code. You could use Pydantic in your own code for your validations, but there's no way for FastAPI to do it for you in that case.

So, in your case, the router should be as,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
        industry: str = Form(...),
        file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    # rest of your logic
    return {"industry": industry, "filename": file.filename}
```

Comment: Now, when I pass inputs through postman, I am getting an error with industry, It is returning No, please check the screenshot, in the predict function I wrote a if condition where if industry is None return No

Comment: @user_12 Updated the answer

Comment: what does that `...` represent

Comment: It is the [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis). In FastAPI, we can set a parameter/argument as [***required***](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#make-it-required) by using this `...` value @user_12