# FastAPI Multipart/form data error when uploading File with JSON data

Tags: python, multipartform-data, fastapi, pydantic

#### My `Pydantic` model looks like ths:

```py
class Banner:
    title: str
    text: str
```

#### My route looks like this:

```py
@router.post('', status_code=201)
async def create_banner(
    banner: Banner,
    photo: UploadFile = File(...)  # multipart/form-data

):
    return await Banners.create(banner.dict())
```

#### But FastAPI returns the following error:

[image]

Comment: You might need to send the JSON data formatted as JSON instead: `{"banner": {"title": "bar", "text": "foo"}`. You can also append the content-type for the JSON itself by appending `; type=application/json` after the JSON iirc.

Answer (score 9):

## Update

Please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) for more options on how to upload a `File` together with `JSON` data.

##### Original answer

In short, [you can't have](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#about-form-fields) Pydantic models (`JSON` data) defined together with `Form` (and/or `File`) data. You can either use [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) fields, i.e, sending the data as `form-data` in the body:

```
@router.post("/")
def create_banner(title: str = Form(...), text: str = Form(...), photo: UploadFile = File(...)):
        return {"JSON Payload ": {"title": title, "text": text}, "Uploaded Filename": photo.filename}
```

or, use [Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) with Pydantic models, i.e., sending the data as `query` parameters:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import Depends

class Banner(BaseModel):
    title: str
    text: str

@router.post("/")
def create_banner(banner: Banner = Depends(), photo: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"JSON Payload ": banner.dict(), "Uploaded Filename": photo.filename}
```

Comment: I had spent days on this and your answer was FINALLY something that was helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/#define-file-and-form-parameters):

> You can declare multiple `File` and `Form` parameters in a path operation,
> but you can't also declare `Body` fields that you expect to receive as
> JSON, as the request will have the body encoded using
> `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`.
>
> This is not a limitation of **FastAPI**, it's part of the HTTP protocol.

And when passing an object, FastAPI will try to treat it as a body specification, not as a form field. That means, you have to explicitly define your `banner` argument as a form field:

```
@router.post('', status_code=201)
async def create_banner(
    banner: Banner = Form(...),
    photo: UploadFile = File(...)  # multipart/form-data

):
    return await Banners.create(banner.dict())
```

Make also sure that your `Banner` object is a valid pydantic model, as FastAPI can't recognize bare objects properly in this context.

Comment: It doesnt work with pydantic models, so you should use this solution: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2387