# FastAPI Post request is not rendering jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, api, jinja2, fastapi

I have made up the post call and render the jinja2 template of login_form.html

`main.py`:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, HTTPException, Depends
import hashlib
from fastapi import APIRouter, Form
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.post("/",response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_form(
    request: Request, uname: str = Form(...), passcode: str = Form(...)
):
    print(uname, passcode)
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "auth/login_form.html", {"request": request,"result": "res"}
    )
```

`login_form.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<form method="post">
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="username"></input>
<h5>Password</h5>
<input name="passcode" placeholder="password" type="text"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>

<p>{{result}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page on web browser I get:

```
{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

[image: loading the webpage of]

Comment: Opening it from browser is a GET request, instead you declared a POST one

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani yes but i have seen the jinja2 and fastAPI tutorials that POST requests open like this because it return the html Page at the end

Comment: Sorry, seeing the image and reading your words i thought you tried to access the page from a direct request instead of submitting the form

Comment: I still think @FedericoProvenziani is correct; where is the GET endpoint that displays the template? Since you're not doing anything with the template in the POST endpoint, it seems like that was meant to be a regular GET endpoint?

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414202/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73359311/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804)

Answer (score 1):

You need two routes first get the template then make post:

```
@app.get("/")
@app.post("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work in the browser, `login_form()` will have to be a `GET` endpoint.

If you've seen examples using `POST` with FastAPI, that's probably because that was for building an API rather than a web app (maybe [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/) is what you're actually looking for).

In order to make your solution work in the browser (with FastAPI) you can add another endpoint (which I'm calling `POST /handle-form`). You will also have to adapt your `login_form.html` template (see below).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_form(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "auth/login_form.html", {"request": request, "result": "res"}
    )

@app.post("/handle-form")
async def handle_form(
    request: Request,
    uname: str = Form(...),
    passcode: str = Form(...),
):
    print(uname, passcode)
```

The only change to `login_form.html` is adding `action="handle-form"` to the `form` tag, where `handle-form` is the the path to the endpoint to post the form data to:

```html
...
<form action="handle-form" method="post">
...
```

It renders like this:

[image]

Once you've entered the username and password and pressed `Submit`, `uname` and `passcode` will be sent to `handle_form()`.