# How to redirect the user back to the home page using FastAPI, after submitting an HTML form?

Tags: python, http, web, jinja2, fastapi

I have a page with a table of students. I added a button that allows you to add a new row to the table. To do this, I redirect the user to a page with input forms.

The problem is that after submitting the completed forms, the user goes to a new empty page. How to transfer data in completed forms and redirect the user back to the table?

I just started learning web programming, so I decided to first make an implementation without using AJAX technologies.

Code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form
from fastapi.responses import Response

import json
from jinja2 import Template

app = FastAPI()


# The page with the table
@app.get('/')  
def index():
    students = get_students()  # Get a list of students
    with open('templates/students.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        html = file.read()
    template = Template(html)  # Creating a template with a table

    # Loading a template
    return Response(template.render(students=students), media_type='text/html')


# Page with forms for adding a new entry
@app.get('/add_student')
def add_student_page():
    with open('templates/add_student.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        html = file.read()

    # Loading a page
    return Response(html, media_type='text/html')


# Processing forms and adding a new entry
@app.post('/add')
def add(name: str = Form(...), surname: str = Form(...), _class: str = Form(...)):
    add_student(name, surname, _class)  # Adding student data
    # ???
```

Comment: It turns out that after clicking the "Add" button, the data from the form is sent to the /add method and the user goes to the same page, which is empty.

Comment: And I need the data from the form to be sent to /add, and the user goes to the main page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, in cases where you return Jinja2 templates, you should return a `TemplateResponse`, as shown in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/). To redirect the user to a specific page, you can use [RedirectResponse](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/es/advanced/custom-response/#redirectresponse). Since you do that through a POST (and not GET) method, as shown in your example, a `405 (Method Not Allowed)` error would be thrown. However, thanks to @[tiangolo](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1498#issuecomment-647040401), you can [change the response status code](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-change-status-code/) to `status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER`, and the issue will then be resolved (please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047991/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414202/17865804) for more details). A working example is given below.

In case you needed to pass additional *path* and/or *query* parameters to your endpoint, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656412/how-to-redirect-to-dynamic-url-inside-fastapi-endpoint/70658754#70658754) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804) answer as well.

In case you had to do the same, **using Fetch API instead** of HTML `<form>`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804).

### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form, status
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

# replace with your own get_students() method
def get_students():
    return ["a", "b", "c"]

@app.post('/add')
async def add(request: Request, name: str = Form(...), surname: str = Form(...), _class: str = Form(...)):
    # add_student(name, surname, _class)  # Adding student data
    redirect_url = request.url_for('index')    
    return RedirectResponse(redirect_url, status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)    

@app.get('/add_student')
async def add_student_page(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("add_student.html", {"request": request})

@app.get('/')
async def index(request: Request):
    students = get_students()  # Get a list of students
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "students": students})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Students: {{ students }}</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

templates/**add_student.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/add" method="POST">
         name : <input type="text" name="name"><br>
         surname : <input type="text" name="surname"><br>
         class : <input type="text" name="_class"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```