# Why doesn't the browser refresh the page?

Tags: fastapi

The application runs on FastAPI. After receiving the POST request, the backend processes the information and must return the main page. The browser receives a 200 OK GET request, but does not go to this page. What am I doing wrong?

```
@router.post("/post_products", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def products_page(response: Response, product_data: List[ProductData]):
    # Some Logic
    return RedirectResponse(url="/login", status_code=302)
```

I tried to perform the task in different browsers (Chrome & Firefox), including incognito mode

Comment: _The browser receives a 200 OK GET request_ Browsers don't **receive** requests. 
 They **make** requests, and they receive **responses**.  What did you actually mean here?

Comment: In addition, your code is showing a POST request, so this can't be the page that returns a 200 OK on a GET request.

Comment: And last, it depends on _how_ you're calling the endpoint - if you're making a `fetch` / javascript request, redirects does not cause the browser to be redirected to a new location.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804) answer your question? Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047991/17865804) as well.