# Passing values from POST and GET methods in FastAPI

Tags: javascript, python, html, backend, fastapi

My goal is to redirect user to **books** page and get data from an input field.
The thing is that when i follow the link, data doesn't seem to follow `get_books()` function and I get something like `AttributeError: 'Body' object has no attribute 'casefold'`

Python code

```py
@app.post('/get_books')
async def get_books(prompt = Body()):
    print(prompt)
    book_list = []
    for book in BOOKS:
        if book.get('title').casefold() == prompt.casefold() or book.get('author').casefold() == prompt.casefold() or book.get('category').casefold() == prompt.casefold():
            book_list.append(book)
    return book_list


@app.get('/books', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def books(request: Request):
    book_list = await get_books()
    print('hi')
    return templates.TemplateResponse("books.html", {"request": request, 'book_list': book_list})
```

HTML element used to redirect
`<a id="btn" class="main__arrow" href="/books"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></a>`

JS code

```js
const el = document.getElementById('btn');

el.addEventListener('click', async function(){
 
    // получаем введеное в поле имя и возраст
    const info = document.getElementById("prompt").value;
    // const userage = document.getElementById("userage").value;

    // отправляем запрос
    const response = await fetch("/get_books", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                info: info
            })
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            // const data = await response.json();
            // document.getElementById("message").textContent = data.message;
        }
        else
            console.log(response);
});
```

I've tried using Form() but it only allows to get info from inputs.
What is the proper way to just redirect to another page and get info that i entered?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047991/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is

1. Fetch the data and store it in `sessionStorage`.
2. Redirect to your new page and have it read the data from `sessionStorage`.

Use a dud href for starters:

```js
<a id="btn" role="button" class="main__arrow" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

Next in your handler store the data in sessionStorage and redirect:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('btn');

el.addEventListener('click', async function(){
 
    const info = document.getElementById("prompt").value;

    const response = await fetch("/get_books", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                info: info
            })
        });
    if (response.data) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(response.data));
    }
    else {
        console.log(response);
    }
    window.location.href = '/books';
});
```

Comment: is JSON.stringify(response.data) right?
what is response.data that we are passing?

Comment: response.data is basically your book list you get from the post api. You don't need to call get_books() in your get handler. The error you are getting is because you are calling the post handler from your get handler directly. In case you want a single api, just have your get api read the info via a query parameter/body, do the functionality get_books does and return your required html.

Comment: the thing is that i was trying to get body and redirect via href but i guess they both conflict together because fetch requires it to be post method

Comment: The problem you are having is in this line ` book_list = await get_books()`. get_books() expects a body. You are not supplying a body when you call it directly.

Comment: How should my parameters to async def get_books(???): look 
and what do i pass when i call await get_books(???) directly

Comment: "In case you want a single api, just have your get api read the info via a query parameter/body" - Then it has to be POST to receive fetch or am i wrong?

Comment: No it doesnt have to be a POST. You can send info in your parameter list of get request. And have it render your html page.