# Is it possible to redirect a get request to another API?

Tags: python, fastapi, influxdb

I want to use FastAPI as a translator/interface to a InfluxDB database. This enables me to simplify the endpoints other apps/clients need to call to.

The main endpoints would be /preview, where you could get a small preview of the datasets you want to get, and /data, where you would get a full copy of the data. Those datasets however, can be quite large (sometimes up to hundreds of MB/some GB). For that reason, I don't want to first load the data from Influx DB to FastAPI and then from FastAPI to the client, but instead "redirect" the request of the client with the proper parameters set to Influx DB. Is something like that possible at all?

I made a picture to illustrate what I mean:
[image: requests flow]

Comment: Just return an HTTP redirect response to the client that directs them to the db…?!

Comment: I didn't know that that's a thing. Sorry, I'm quite new to HTTP stuff. So I could do a redirect, which also has the correct request settings as body?

Comment: @Jan you should be able to have your API return an instance of RedirectResponse from starlette (the core framework FastAPI is built on top of). `from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse`

Comment: Note however, that if this is for a browser application, you may need to configure Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) rules. (Browsers don't typically like when a webpage makes call outs to random other domains, because this can be used to exploit things like local secrets/cookies for the current domain).

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to configure InfluxDB for CORS aswell? I'll read into that :)

Comment: As already mentioned, you could use `RedirectResponse`. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804) for more details and examples. In case you would like the FastAPI app returning the response back to the client, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804).