# Frontend HTML refreshes after a POST request, updated elements will go back to being what they were previously

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, post, axios, fastapi

I use FastAPI with Python to run the backend of the server. I am trying to connect the local frontend client with the local backend server. I am able to submit a POST request and the server, the server is being updated with new data (URL, password, shortened URL). I use `axios()` to POST my request, and use `.then` to get the response and update selected element.

My issue comes from the frontend receiving the data, then updating my `<h1>` element and `console.log()` the JSON data before immediately refreshing, removing or undoing all changes.

Server
POST: http://127.0.0.1:8000/url

My frontend portion

```
    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="inputField">Enter your URL:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputField" name="url" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h1 id="short_url"></h1>

    <script>
        const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        form.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const longURL = formData.get("url");
            axios
                .post(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/url",
                    { target_url: longURL },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        },
                    }
                )
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data.admin_url);
                    document.getElementById("short_url").textContent = response.data;
                });
        });
    </script>
```

My backend portion where the POST request happens

```
@app.post("/url", response_model=schemas.URLInfo)
def create_url(url: schemas.URLBase, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if not validators.url(url.target_url):
        raise_bad_request(message="Your provided URL is not valid")

    db_url = crud.create_db_url(db=db, url=url)
    return get_admin_info(db_url)
```

I have tried using `return false` at the end of frontend, using `fetch()` instead of `axios()`, expecting the update to stick but result is still the same, instant refresh of less than 1~5 seconds.

I have also tried using `setTimeout()`, but the speed at which it refresh is still the same.

What was successful was purposefully causing an error, it would no longer refresh but immediately following that, if I add in a proper URL, it would refresh the whole webpage.

Lastly, I have checked my database every POST request and it is constantly being updated with new data that I input.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related answers that you might find helpful can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73358937/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804)