# How to send response from a POST to a GET route in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to send data from app.post() to app.get()

```
@app.get("/predict", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def get_predict(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("predict.html", {"request": request})
```

```
@app.post("/predict", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def predict(
    request: Request,
    mintempC: float = Form(...),
    maxtempC: float = Form(...),
    humidity: float = Form(...),
    DewPointC: float = Form(...),
    pressure: float = Form(...),
    cloudcover: float = Form(...),
    visibility: float = Form(...),
    precipMM: float = Form(...),
    city :    int = Form(...),  
    raintoday: int = Form(...),
):
    
    pred = model.predict([[maxtempC, mintempC, DewPointC, cloudcover, humidity, pressure, visibility, precipMM, city, raintoday]])[0]
    output = pred
    if output == 0:
        return templates.TemplateResponse("after_sunny.html", {"request": request})
    else:
        return templates.TemplateResponse("after_rainy.html", {"request": request})
```

im getting the error starlette.routing.NoMatchFound: No route exists for name "static" and params "filename".

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Also, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804), regarding `starlette.routing.NoMatchFound` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RedirectResponse` instead in fastAPI :

```py
# the post method

from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

...
output = "after_sunny.html" if pred == 0 else "after_rainy.html"
return RedirectResponse(url=f"/predict?output={output}")
```

And a little bit change withing the `get` method:

```py
@app.get("/predict", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def get_predict(request: Request, output: str = None):
    if output == "after_sunny.html":
        return templates.TemplateResponse("after_sunny.html", {"request": request})
    elif output == "after_rainy.html":
        return templates.TemplateResponse("after_rainy.html", {"request": request})
    else:
        return templates.TemplateResponse("predict.html", {"request": request})
```