# Within Python v 3.12, is there a more efficient way dynamically building HTML than this

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

Edit: I'm using Jinja2 for my frontend and FastAPI/Python 3.12 on the backend.

My goal is to use HTMX (AJAX) when a user clicks an element that was rendered in their browser to call my backend api fetch some HTML and them update the DOM based on backend generated HTML.  With that said I quickly found myself thinking what I'm doing is less then efficient.

Very simply; I want to create the HTML Code for, let's say something simple, like a select dropdown list with values from 1 - 10. While this is a simple example, I can imagine I will run into more involved scenarios later but for the purposes of this question let's keep it simple.

here is my code:

async def html_test():

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
my_html = '<select name="test" class="form-control">'

for item in my_list:
    my_html = my_html + '<option value="'
    my_html = my_html + f'{item}'
    my_html = my_html + '">'
    my_html = my_html + f'{item}'
    my_html = my_html + '</option>'

my_html = my_html + '</select>'
return my_html
```

This code works fine; but I just feel like there could be a better way as this "feels" wrong.

In a previous life, I had an opportunity to code with Coldfusion and that language had a function called CFSAVECONTENT that automatically saved everything inside of the opening and closing tags to a variable. You could loop, set new variables, perform if statements, really anything you wanted or needed right within the string portion itself.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't know your perticular use case but I would prefer to use a templating language such as Jinja in you case: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/. It puts all the formatting and looping logic outisde of your Python code so the result would be much cleaner

Comment: Thank you @SamuelRIGAUD for the comment. I have updated the question to be a bit more clear. I'm already using Jinja2 as my templating language. My goal is to update the dom with new/updated html AFTER the jinja2 template was already rendered in the client browser. This action would be triggered by a click on a button, etc.  Thank you though for being the first to comment!!! Very much appreciated!

Comment: In addition to the link above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73358937/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804) (see Option 4, specifically).