# fastapi When I try to login by sending a Post request with js, I get a 422 Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: python, fastapi

This js code below is the code that sends a login request to my fastapi server in React.

```js
    const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: Username,
                password: Password,
            }),
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setCookie("access_token", res.data.access_token);
                setCookie("token_type", res.data.token_type);
                setCookie("username", res.data.username);
                setCookie("is_login", true);
                navigate(`/`);
                return;
            }
            if (res.status === 401) {
                alert("Incorrect username or password");
                return;
            }
            alert("Error");
        });
    };
```

The Python code below is the code that handles login requests in my Fastapi.

```
@router.post("/login", response_model=schemas.Token)
def login_for_access_token(
        form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
        db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    user = crud.get_user_by_username(db, form_data.username)
    if not user or not crud.pwd_context.verify(form_data.password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )

    data = {
        "sub": user.username,
        "exp": datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    }
    access_token = jwt.encode(data, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)

    print(f"access_token: {access_token} (type: {type(access_token)})")

    return schemas.Token(
        access_token=access_token,
        token_type="bearer",
        username=user.username
    )
```

`<starlette.requests.Request object at 0x000001E784693E50> 2 validation errors for Request body -> username field required (type=value_error.missing) body -> password field required (type=value_error.missing)`

My error code is as above.

Maybe my question is stupid

I am getting this 422 error because the data type is different. I know what happens when there is no data. In my case, when I look at the error code, there is no data, but I don't know why there is no data.

I tried changing the header to `"content-type": "application/json"` and creating an exception_handler to display an error message, but I still don't know why this problem occurs.

Comment: To post file/form data instead, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74507628/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73359311/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711008/17865804).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I POST a x-www-form-urlencoded request using Fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325370/how-do-i-post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-using-fetch)

I solved it through the question above.

In fastapi, receiving it through application/x-www-form-urlencoded. JS was sending it to json, just with the header

So I sent the post request using the link above, and it worked well

Thank you to everyone who answered