# how to display alert messages with jinja2?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, fastapi

I'm building a todo app with fastapi. I've been trying to display alert messages with jinja2 'TemplateResponse' and it partially works, the alert is displayed but I'm redirected to a new page, which is not the result I want. I'm not sure how to display the alerts in the same page.

app.py

```
@app.post("/add")
async def add(request: Request, title:str = Form(...), db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    #checking if todo exists
    existing_todo = db.query(models.Todo).filter(models.Todo.title == title).first()
    if existing_todo:
        message=("todo already exists",)
        return templates.TemplateResponse("base.html", {"request": request, "alert": message})
    
    new_todo=models.Todo(title=title)
    try:
        db.add(new_todo)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
    except:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500,detail={"Error": "An error ocurred"})

    url= app.url_path_for("home")
    return RedirectResponse(url=url, status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
```

base.html

```
<body>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="ui container">
        <h1 class="ui center aligned header">To Do App</h1>

        <form class="ui form" action="/add" method="POST">
            {%if alert %}
            {%for message in alert%}
            <div class="ui orange message">{{message}}</div>
            {%endfor%}
            {%endif%}
            <div class="field">
                <label>Todo Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Todo..."><br>
            </div>
            <button class="ui blue button" type="submit">Add</button>
            <a class="ui red button" href="/delete-all">Delete ALL</a>
        </form>

        <hr>

        {% for todo in todo_list %}
        <div class="ui segment">
            <p class="ui big header">{{todo.id }} | {{ todo.title }}</p>

            {% if todo.complete == False %}
            <span class="ui gray label">Not Completed</span>
            {% else %}
            <span class="ui green label">Completed</span>
            {% endif %}

            <a class="ui blue button" href="/update/{{ todo.id }}">Update</a>
            <a class="ui red button" href="/delete/{{ todo.id }}">Delete</a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        
    </div>
</body>
```

is there something I'm missing?

Comment: if you need to get some data from server without reloading page then you have to use `JavaScript` and so called `AJAX`. `HTML` (`<form>`) always reloads page.

Comment: Related answers to the one above can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73359311/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804) (Option 4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) (Option 2).