# How to upload both file and JSON data using FastAPI?

Tags: python, multipartform-data, fastapi, pydantic

This is my Pydantic model:

```
class Base(BaseModel):
    name: str
    point: Optional[float] = None
    is_accepted: Optional[bool] = False
```

This is the endpoint:

```
def create_base(
    base: Base = Form(...),
    file: List[UploadFile] = File(...)
):
...
```

I'm trying to send a request via multipart form, but i'm getting the error:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "base"
            ],
            "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
            "type": "type_error.dict"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the payload of my request:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "point": 10.0,
  "is_accepted": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sending form data or a JSON body? Your example seems to indicate you're sending JSON, but you're using `Form` and mentioning multipart form-data.

Comment: Yeah, I want to send a JSON to this specific object (Base) but in a multipart form-data. Is this possible? I need to send this specific boundary (base) in json and also the files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request)

Answer (score 4):

## Update

Please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) for more details and options.

---

As per [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#about-form-fields),

> You can declare multiple `Form` parameters in a path operation, but **you
> can't also declare `Body` fields that you expect to receive as `JSON`**, as
> the request will have the body encoded using
> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json` (when the form includes files, it is encoded as `multipart/form-data`).
>
> This is not a limitation of FastAPI, it's part of the `HTTP` protocol.

### **Method 1**

So, as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/), one can define files and form fields at the same time using `File` and `Form`. Below is a working example:

**app.py**

```
from fastapi import Form, File, UploadFile, Request, FastAPI
from typing import List
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.post("/submit")
def submit(name: str = Form(...), point: float = Form(...), is_accepted: bool  = Form(...), files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
        return {"JSON Payload ": {"name": name, "point": point, "is_accepted": is_accepted}, "Filenames": [file.filename for file in files]}

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

You can test it by accessing the template below at http://127.0.0.1:8000

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         name : <input type="text" name="name" value="foo"><br>
         point : <input type="text" name="point" value=0.134><br>
         is_accepted : <input type="text" name="is_accepted" value=True><br>    
         <label for="file">Choose files to upload</label>
         <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can also test it through OpenAPI docs (Swagger UI) at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs or Python requests, as shown below:

**test.py**

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit'
files = [('files', open('test_files/a.txt', 'rb')), ('files', open('test_files/b.txt', 'rb'))]
payload ={"name": "foo", "point": 0.13, "is_accepted": False}
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, files = files) 
print(resp.json())
```

### **Method 2**

One can use Pydantic models, along with [Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) to inform the "submit" route (in the case below) that the parameterised variable `base` depends on the `Base` class. Please note, this method expects the `base` data as query (not body) parameters (which are then converted into an equivalent JSON Payload using `.dict()` method) and the Files as `multipart/form-data` in the body.

**app.py**

```
from fastapi import Form, File, UploadFile, Request, FastAPI, Depends
from typing import List
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

class Base(BaseModel):
    name: str
    point: Optional[float] = None
    is_accepted: Optional[bool] = False

@app.post("/submit")
def submit(base: Base = Depends(), files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    received_data= base.dict()
    return {"JSON Payload ": received_data, "Uploaded Filenames": [file.filename for file in files]}
 
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

Again, you can test it with the template below:

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form method="post" id="myForm" onclick="transformFormData();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         name : <input type="text" name="name" value="foo"><br>
         point : <input type="text" name="point" value=0.134><br>
         is_accepted : <input type="text" name="is_accepted" value=True><br>    
         <label for="file">Choose files to upload</label>
         <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
      <script>
         function transformFormData(){
            var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
            var qs = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(myForm)).toString();
            myForm.action = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit?'+qs;
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

As mentioned earlier you can use Swagger UI, or the Python requests example below:

**test.py**

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit'
files = [('files', open('test_files/a.txt', 'rb')), ('files', open('test_files/b.txt', 'rb'))]
payload ={"name": "foo", "point": 0.13, "is_accepted": False}
resp = requests.post(url=url, params=payload, files=files)
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: If the answer is already provided in another existing Q&A pair, [please vote to close as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) instead, rather than copying and fragmenting the answers into multiple similar posts.