# How to submit data using HTML in the frontend and get the results from FastAPI backend?

Tags: javascript, python, json, api, fastapi

I am using FastAPI for the backend and HTML/CSS for the frontend. I want to click the button and get the wanted value in return (`mt` means when I put `node1` and `node2` it gets me its prediction from the JSON array.

This is my code:

**This is the data list**

```
prediction_data = [
  { "node1": 0, "node2": 1, "pred": 0},
  { "node1": 0, "node2": 476, "pred":0.352956 },
  { "node1": 0, "node2": 494, "pred":0.769988 },
  { "node1": 1, "node2": 505, "pred":0.463901 },
  { "node1": 9, "node2": 68 , "pred":1.238807},
  { "node1": 15, "node2": 408, "pred":0.204171 },
  { "node1": 18, "node2":549 , "pred":0.204171 },
  { "node1": 60, "node2": 227, "pred":0.204171 },
  { "node1": 199, "node2": 220, "pred":0.245246 },
  { "node1": 170, "node2": 570, "pred":0.509272 },
  { "node1": 148, "node2": 570, "pred":0.204171 },
  { "node1": 151, "node2": 384, "pred":0.204114 },
  { "node1": 232, "node2": 337, "pred":0.285999 },
  { "node1": 446, "node2": 509, "pred":0.291206 },
  { "node1": 510, "node2":576 , "pred":0.495378 },
  { "node1": 571, "node2":589 , "pred":0 },
  { "node1": 585, "node2":596 , "pred":0.245243 },
  { "node1": 446, "node2":509 , "pred":0.291206 },
  { "node1": 375, "node2":383 , "pred":0.46390 },
  { "node1": 461, "node2":462 , "pred":0 }
    ]
```

**This the getter function of the wanted value**

```
# Prediction
@app.get("/prediction/{node1,node2}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def gets(request: Request, node1: int, node2: int):
    matching = list(filter(lambda x: x['node1'] == node1 and x['node2'] == node2, prediction_data))
    mt = matching[0]['pred'] if matching else None
    return templates.TemplateResponse("Interface.html", {"request": request, "mt": mt})
```

**This is the interface**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Link Prediction</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" >
        <h1>Link Prediction </h1>
        <h2>In Social Network</h2>
        <form class="form" action="#">
          <fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __first">
            <input type="number" id="Node1" tabindex="0" /> {{node1}}
            <label for="Node1">
              <span data-text="Node 1">Node 1</span>
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          
          <fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __second">
            <input  type="number" id="Node2" tabindex="0" /> {{node2}}
            <label for="Node2">
              <span data-text="Node 2">Node 2 </span>
            </label>
          </fieldset>

          <div class="form-footer">
            <button  onclick="myfunctionName(Node1, Node2)" class="btn">Predict Now</button>
          </div>

          <script type="text/javascript">
              
              function myfunctionName( n1,n2 ){
          
                  document.getElementById("Node1").innerHTML += n1;
                  document.getElementById("Node2").innerHTML += n2;
                  document.getElementById("Prediction") = mt;
              }
          
          </script>

<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __third">
    <input type="text" id="Prediction" readonly/> {{mt}}
    <label for="Prediction">
      <span data-text="Prediction Result" >Prediction Result</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
          
        </form>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you should have a look at how [Path parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/) work in FastAPI. The following in your code `@app.get("/prediction/{node1,node2}` is not a valid route for passing path parameters. It will instead be recognised as a single path name. You can verify this by opening Swagger UI
at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs, which shows that the endpoint expects `node1` and `node2` to be **query** params, not path params. When submitting form data, one should use [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) fields for that purpose, and `POST` HTTP method (your endpoint should be using `@app.post()`)—browsers cache `GET` requests (i.e., saved in browser's history), thus making them less secure compared to POST—have a look at [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804). If you still, however, need this to be a GET request, you can use a GET operation `@app.get()` in your API, as well as define the method for your HTML form being `method="GET"` (but wouldn't recommend it).

**Backend**:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('predict.html', {'request': request})

@app.post('/predict', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def predict(request: Request, node1: int = Form(...), node2: int = Form(...)):
    matching = list(filter(lambda x: x['node1'] == node1 and x['node2'] == node2, prediction_data))
    mt = matching[0]['pred'] if matching else None
    return templates.TemplateResponse("predict.html", {"request": request, "node1": node1, "node2": node2, "mt": mt})
```

**Frontend** template (i.e., **predict.html** in your case):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <body>
      <h1>Link Prediction </h1>
      <h2>In Social Network</h2>
      <form method="POST" action="/predict" id="myForm">
         node1 : <input type="text" name="node1" value={{node1}}> <br>
         node2 : <input type="text" name="node2" value={{node2}}><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Predict" >
      </form>
      Prediction Result: <b>{{mt}}</b>
   </body>
</html>
```