# How do I display the results from FastAPI to a webpage after button click?

Tags: html, python-3.x, fastapi

So I made an API that takes the images, predicts using a model and I want to display the results of the model

The code for API:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Request
import uvicorn
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import os
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

origins = [
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://127.0.0.1:80",
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates/")

MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("./Skin Cancer.h5")

# CLASS_NAMES = ["", ""]
classes = {4: ('nv', ' melanocytic nevi'),
           6: ('mel', 'melanoma'),
           2 :('bkl', 'benign keratosis-like lesions'), 
           1:('bcc' , ' basal cell carcinoma'),
           5: ('vasc', ' pyogenic granulomas and hemorrhage'),
           0: ('akiec', 'Actinic keratoses and intraepithelial carcinomae'),
           3: ('df', 'dermatofibroma')}

def model_predict(img_path, MODEL):
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(img_path, target_size = (28,28))
    img = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    img_data = preprocess_input(img)
    preds = MODEL.predict(img_data)
    return preds

def save_upload_file_tmp(upload_file: UploadFile) -> Path:
    try:
        suffix = Path(upload_file.filename).suffix
        with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=suffix) as tmp:
            shutil.copyfileobj(upload_file.file, tmp)
            tmp_path = Path(tmp.name)
    finally:
        upload_file.file.close()
    return tmp_path

@app.get("/ping")
def ping():
    return "pinging!"

@app.get("/")
def home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {'request':request})

# @app.post("/")
# def home(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
#     return templates.TemplateResponse("base.html", {'request':request})


@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
    request: Request,
    file: UploadFile = File(...)

):

    # basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # file_path = os.path.join(basepath,"chest_xray/val", file.filename)
    filepath = save_upload_file_tmp(file)
    print(filepath)
    predictions = model_predict(filepath, MODEL)

    filepath.unlink()
    # predictions = model_predict(file_path, MODEL)

    # predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    # confidence = np.max(predictions[0])
    class_lab = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    class_score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    conf = float(np.max(predictions[0]))*100

    cl = class_lab[tf.argmax(class_score)]
    cancer_name = classes[cl][1]

    return templates.TemplateResponse("pred.html", {'request': request,'Class':cancer_name, 'Confidence':conf})
    # return{
    #     'class' : cancer_name,
    #     'confidence' : float(conf)*100
    # }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=80)
```

I want to render the preds.html file after user clicks the predict button on the index.html
It will redirect them to new page preds.html and display the results in a grid with image and score on website

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771526/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73359311/17865804)