# How to include JSON and File data together in FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, http, fastapi

I would like to POST `JSON` and `File` data together, as shown in the code below:

**fastapi.py**

```py
@router.post('/rate')
def users(user_review:schemas.Rate, image123: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session=Depends(get_db)):
    print(image123)
```

**schemas.py**

```py
class Rate(BaseModel):
    id1:int
    id2:int
    message:Optional[str] = None
    rate:conint(ge=1, le=5)
```

However, when I execute it, it throws the following `422` error:

```json
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "user_review"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        },
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "image123"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that you haven't included any values for those fields - your request does not match what the API expects. You can use `response_model` for the endpoint to tell FastAPI how to format what you return from the view function - in your case you're not returning anything - so there is no response to format either.

Comment: @MatsLindh The issue is not only that values for the required fields were not included in the request, but also, that the endpoint expects `JSON` data and `form-data` at the same time, which is not possible, as explained in the link provided above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request)

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare an endpoint that expects both `JSON` and `File`/`Form` data together, as this is not supported by the `HTTP` protocol, as explained in [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#about-form-fields). When a request includes `Form` data, it will have the `body` encoded using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`; if `File` data are included as well, it will have the `body` encoded using `multipart/form-data`.

As explained in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), there are various methods to send additional data together with uploading `Files`. The below demonstrates an approach based on **Method 4** of the above answer.

**Note:** You shouldn't name your python script file **fastapi.py** (as shown in your question), as this would interfere with the library (when using, for example, `from fastapi import FastAPI`), but rather use some neutral name, such as **app.py**.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Body
from pydantic import BaseModel, conint, model_validator
from typing import Optional
import json

app = FastAPI()

class Rate(BaseModel):
    id1: int
    id2: int
    message: Optional[str] = None
    rate: conint(ge=1, le=5)

    @model_validator(mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def validate_to_json(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return cls(**json.loads(value))
        return value
    
@app.post("/rate")
def submit(user_review: Rate = Body(...), image: UploadFile = File(...)):
        return {"JSON Payload ": user_review, "Image": image.filename}
```

**test.py**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/rate'
file = {'image': open('image.png','rb')}
data = {'user_review': '{"id1": 1, "id2": 2, "message": "foo", "rate": 5}'}
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=data, files=file) 
print(resp.json())
```

**Test with Fetch API (using [`Jinja2Templates`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates) or [`HTMLResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#html-response))**

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">       
         function submitData() {
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('imageFile');
            if (fileInput.files[0]) {
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append("user_review", JSON.stringify({id1: 1, id2: 2, message: "foo", rate: 5}));
                data.append("image", fileInput.files[0]);
                fetch('/rate', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: data
                    })
                    .then(resp => resp.text())  // or, resp.json(), etc.
                    .then(data => {
                        document.getElementById("responseArea").innerHTML = data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="file" id="imageFile" name="file"></br></br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitData()">
      <div id="responseArea"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```