# Error: {loc: ["body"], msg: "value is not a valid dict", type: "type_error.dict"} when sending files from React to FastAPI

Tags: reactjs, json, fastapi, pydantic

I'm building a file upload feature using React and FastAPI. However, I'm encountering an error when attempting to send files from React to FastAPI. The error message I'm receiving is: {loc: ["body"], msg: "value is not a valid dict", type: "type_error.dict"}.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
export default function FileUploader() {
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOveride, setSelectedOveride] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const numFilesSelected = event.target.files.length;
    setSelectedFiles([...selectedFiles, ...event.target.files]);
    // Create an array with the number of selected files times false
    const falseArray = new Array(numFilesSelected).fill(false);
    console.log(event.target.files.length)
    setSelectedOveride([...selectedOveride, ...falseArray]);
  };

  const handleOverrideChange = (index) => {
    setSelectedOveride((prevOveride) => {
      const updatedOveride = [...prevOveride];
      updatedOveride[index] = !updatedOveride[index];
      return updatedOveride;
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveFile = (index) => {
    const files = [...selectedFiles];
    const overide = [...selectedOveride];
    overide.splice(index,1);
    setSelectedOveride(overide);
    files.splice(index,1);
    setSelectedFiles(files);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch('/api/uploadfile/', {
        method: 'POST',
        // headers: {
        //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // },
        body: JSON.stringify({files: selectedFiles, override: selectedOveride})
      });
      // console.log(await resp.json())
      const [ data, completed, exists ] = await resp.json();
      console.log(data)
      console.log(completed)
      console.log(exists)
      // // Update the state with the extracted values
      // if (data === "Error") {
      //   console.error('Error: Failed to connect to Weaviate')
      //   setError('There was an error connecting to Host');
      // } else if (data === "No") {
      //   setError('Invalid credentials for admin login - please logout and try again');
      // } else {
      //   setSuccess(`Uploaded: ${completed.join(', ')}`);
      //   setMessage(`Already Exists: ${exists.join(', ')}`);
      // }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      setError('There was an error connecting to the host');
    }
  };
```

And here's the FastAPI BaseModel I'm using:

```
class userUpload(BaseModel):
    files: List[UploadFile]
    override: List[bool]
```

I believe the issue is with how I'm sending the files and override values from React to FastAPI. I'm using fetch in React to send a JSON payload to the FastAPI endpoint. However, it seems that the payload is not being correctly interpreted as a valid dictionary by FastAPI.

I would appreciate any insights on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you tried printing your request body at router level?  Change the type at router from your pydantic class to a normal dict then try printing at at console see what you are receiving.

Comment: You can't have `UploadFile`s in your JSON body, it must be as a file in a form upload (see [the documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/)). This answer will probably be what you want: [How to include JSON and File data together in FastAPI endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891621/11612918)