# 422 (Unprocessable Entity) When using axios to send file to fastapi

Tags: reactjs, axios, fastapi

handle submit function:

```
const handleSubmit = async (acceptedFiles) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/solidarity",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        console.log(response.data);
        // Handle the response, maybe display the audit results
      } else {
        throw new Error("Server responded with a non-2xx status code");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Error uploading file:",
        error.response?.data || error.message
      );
    }
  };
```

function in python for fastAPI

```
@app.post("/upload")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile):

    data = await file.read()
    save_to = UPLOAD_DIR / file.filename
    with open(save_to, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)

    return {"filenames": file.filename}
```

I'm making a web app in react that audits files, I need it to audit files that are uploaded onto a dropbox.

I've tried checking with different file formats, without using axios and changing the input of fileupload

Comment: don't set `Content-Type`, because it does not contain 'boundary' value which is a must when using `multipart/formdata`. Remove it and axios will automatically add 'multipart' as content-type along with boundary value. [scroll to see warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object)

Comment: Try checkin this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029319/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891621/17865804) as well. You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful.

Comment: @bogdanoff it does not make a difference when I change content type

Comment: oh i actually got it. Well a new error, but got it to work. It works when i changed it from file: UploadFile to request: Request. Tho i'm not too sure why it works.