# Pydantic model inside model with file request body in FastApi

Tags: fastapi, pydantic, payload

I'm having issues using a Pydantic model inside another one along with a file in the request body.

Here is my endpoint definition:

```
async def download_process_videos_csv(
    db: get_db_session,
    payload: ProcessVideoPayload = Depends(),
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
    force: bool = False,
) -> JSONResponse:
```

where `ProcessVideoPayload` is defined as follows:

```
class GenerateVideoModelInfo(BaseModel):
    """Mode setup for the video processing task."""

    ml_model_class: str = "movinet"
    ml_model_name: str = "a2"

    ids: list[int] = [214]
    input_start: int = 0
    input_end: int | None = None
    batch_size: int = 32
    sequence_size: int = 1
    use_precomputed_pickle: bool = False
    video_length: int = 60
    combine_videos: bool = True
    peaks_per_video: int = 1


class ProcessVideoPayload(BaseModel):
    """The base request payload for process video endpoints."""

    folder_name: str = "input_videos"
    ml_model_setup: GenerateVideoModelInfo = GenerateVideoModelInfo()
```

This is how my Swagger UI looks (I'm using default values defined in Pydantic models, and I'm just uploading test.csv):

[image]

But when executing, I'm getting an error "Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from.":

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "model_attributes_type",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "ml_model_setup"
      ],
      "msg": "Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from",
      "input": "{\r\n  \"ml_model_class\": \"movinet\",\r\n  \"ml_model_name\": \"a2\",\r\n  \"ids\": [\r\n    214\r\n  ],\r\n  \"input_start\": 0,\r\n  \"batch_size\": 32,\r\n  \"sequence_size\": 1,\r\n  \"use_precomputed_pickle\": false,\r\n  \"video_length\": 60,\r\n  \"combine_videos\": true,\r\n  \"peaks_per_video\": 1\r\n}",
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/model_attributes_type"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to make it work? When I use the same Pydantic model in another endpoint but without a file in the request body like this:

```
@router.post("/download_process_video", status_code=201)
async def download_process_video(
    db: get_db_session, payload: ProcessVideoPayload, force: bool = False
) -> JSONResponse:
```

It works without any issues. I would like to keep this **ProcessVideoPayload** structure as I need both endpoints with and without uploading a file and I'm using the `payload.ml_model_setup` as input for some function.

Comment: You can't combine a JSON body and a FileUpload (which is form data): see alternatives in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request

Comment: Not exactly. They are not solving the problem with nested data types in `ProcessVideoPayload`. That's the issue. When I don't include `ml_model_setup`, it works. The problem lies with that nested Pydantic model. Perhaps this solution can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221861/8416107 using `payload = ProcessVideoPayload.model_validate_json(payload)` and defining `payload: str = Form(...)`. However, in that case, I'm losing the nice feature of Swagger that shows the expected attributes in the payload.

Comment: But in that case it's not a Pydantic payload, it's just a string parameter. You can't have a JSON body and a UploadFile at the same time - it's the UploadFile that changes the behavior, since they can't be combined, and URL / Form arguments don't support nested models.

Comment: That's basically what I'm asking. How to solve the problem that I need to upload file and information in form of `ProcessVideoPayload`. I can always put the `GenerateVideoModelInfo` out of the `ProcessVideoPayload` and use it as basic endpoint parameters but then I have same problem with its `ids: list[int]`

Comment: I've probably found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891621/8416107

Comment: Yes, that's one of the five ways described in the answer linked - it has five different methods you can use to get around this particular limitation in how requests are structured.