# Question mark in POST method using FastAPI returns 404 error

Tags: python, http, query-string, fastapi, querystringparameter

Could you please explain to me why in FastAPI the following works:

```py
@app.post("/items/v1/cards{sku}")
async def create_item(sku: str):
    return {"status":200,"sku":sku}  # returns status:200 and sku
```

but, the same endpoint with questionmark in it like the one given below does not?

```py
@app.post("/items/v1/cards?{sku}")
async def create_item(sku: str):
    return {"sku":sku}  # returns 404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **first** code snippet, you defined the parameter as a [Path parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/) and worked as expected.

```py
@app.post('/items/v1/cards/{sku}')
async def create_item(sku: str):
    return {'sku': sku}
```

URL Example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/v1/cards/something
```

In the **second** one, however, you attempted to pass a [Query parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) in the wrong way. As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/):

> When you declare other function parameters that are **not** part of the
> path parameters, they are **automatically** interpreted as "query"
> parameters.

Hence, your endpoint should look like this:

```py
@app.post('/items/v1/cards')
async def create_item(sku: str):
    return {'sku': sku}
```

> The query is the set of key-value pairs that go after the `?` in a URL,
> separated by `&` characters.

URL Example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/v1/cards?sku=something
```

Comment: Ohk, thank you @Chris for explaining it . I modified the endpoint as you suggested and it works, thank you for your time.