# How can I pass a URL as a parameter to GET endpoint in FastAPI?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

For example, I have this URL

`https://store.epicgames.com/es-ES/p/dead-island-2--gold-edition`

````py
@app.get("/Datos/{CI}")
async def read_CI(CI: str):
    return{"CI_Datos":CI}```
````

This is my curl

```
curl -X 'GET' \
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Datos/%2F%2F' \
-H 'accept: application/json'
```

and I want the API to be able to get that URL.

I get error `404` when I pass a URL. I understand that the problem is the `/`.

Comment: You need to urlencode it

Comment: If you are looking for how to pass a URL as a path parameter, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804). If you would instead like to pass it as a query parameter, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068032/17865804).

Answer (score 1):

After a little research, I have a solution:

```
@app.get("/Datos")
async def get_url(
    url: str = None
):
    return {"url": url}
```