# How to pass unencoded URL in FastAPI/Swagger UI via GET method?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, urlencode

I would like to write a FastAPI endpoint, with a Swagger page (or something similar) that will accept a non-encoded URL as input. It should preferably use `GET`, **not** `POST` method.

Here's an example of a `GET` endpoint that **does** require double-URL encoding.

```
@app.get("/get_from_dub_encoded/{double_encoded_url}")
async def get_from_dub_encoded(double_encoded_url: str):
    """
    Try https%253A%252F%252Fworld.openfoodfacts.org%252Fapi%252Fv0%252Fproduct%252F7622300489434.json
    """
    original_url = urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.unquote(double_encoded_url))
    response = requests.get(original_url)
    return response.json()
```

Which generates a Swagger interface as below.

The following `PUT` request does solve my problem, but the simplicity of a `GET` request with a `form` is better for my co-workers.

```py
class InputModel(BaseModel):
    unencoded_url: AnyUrl = Field(description="An unencoded URL for an external resource", format="url")


@app.post("/unencoded-url")
def unencoded_url(inputs: InputModel):
    response = requests.get(inputs.unencoded_url)
    return response.json()
```

How can I deploy a convenient interface like that without requiring users to write the payload for a `PUT` request or to perform double URL encoding?

[image]

This post has some helpful related discussion, but doesn't explicitly address the FORM solution: [How to pass URL as a path parameter to a FastAPI route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801333/how-to-pass-url-as-a-path-parameter-to-a-fastapi-route)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass URL as a path parameter to a FastAPI route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801333/how-to-pass-url-as-a-path-parameter-to-a-fastapi-route)

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068032/17865804) as well. I would also highly suggest you use `httpx` instead of Python `requests` module. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804).

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this question, @Chris

Comment: You may also have a look at Options 2 & 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804). I would also suggest you have a look at MDN's documentation on [Sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#the_method_attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Form` instead of query parameters as payload.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form
import requests

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
def get_url(url: str = Form()):

    """
    Try https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/7622300489434.json
    """
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()
```

Swagger interface would look like:
[image]

You'll need to install [`python-multipart`](https://pypi.org/project/python-multipart/).

Tip: Don't use async endpoint if you are using requests or any non-async library.

Comment: Great, I am feeling very optimistic about this. However, when I launch uvicorn, I get this error: "    def unencoded_form(url: str = Form()):
TypeError: Form() missing 1 required positional argument: 'default'"

Comment: It does what I was asking for as long as the function signature looks like this: `def unencoded_form(url: str = Form(default="https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/7622300489434.json")):`. I guess I should just do some reading!

Comment: I guess we're on a different version. My FastAPI is `0.82.0`. 
Also, you can just pass `default=None` in that case.

Comment: This was helpful regarding defaults: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/854