# FastAPI - How to pass a dictionary/JSON data in HTTP multipart request?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, fastapi, multipartform-data

I'm trying to make a `POST` request:

```
import requests


files = {'template': open('template.xlsx', 'rb')}
payload = {
    'context': {
        'OUT': 'csv',
        'SHORT': 'short'
    },
    'filename': 'file.xlsx',
    'content_type': 'application/excel'
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/render', files=files, data=payload)
```

to a FastAPI server:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, Form
from pydantic import Json

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/render')
def render(template: UploadFile, context: Json = Form(), filename: str = Form(...), content_type: str = Form(...)):
    # processing
    return "ok"
```

but I get this error (`422` status code):

```json
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","context"],"msg":"Invalid JSON","type":"value_error.json"}]}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass a `file` and `request body` at the same time. I guess I could fix this if converted `payload['context']` into JSON. But I'd like to fix this on server side.

How can I fix the error? Maybe convert some before params passed into view or something like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to serialise your JSON on client side, using [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps), before sending the request. Additionally, you wouldn't really need to send metadata such as `filename` and `content_type` as part of your JSON payload. You can set the `filename` (which you can customise) and `content_type` explicitly in the [multipart-encoded file](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), which you can later retrieve on server side using the [`UploadFile` attributes](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile). Further, the `content_type` (or `mime type`) of an `.xlsx` file shouldn't be `application/excel`, but, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types), that should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. Finally, I would also suggest you have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request/70640522#70640522), which explains the reason that you can't have both `form-data`/`files` and `JSON` together, and provides solutions that would allow one to submit both, and have the JSON data validated as well—in your case, the JSON data are not validated against a Pydantic model, meaning that the client can send any type of data or ommit any `required` attributes.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, Form, File
from pydantic import Json

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/render')
def render(file: UploadFile = File(...), context: Json = Form()):
    print(context, context['OUT'], file.filename, file.content_type, sep="\n")
    return "ok"
```

**test.py**

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'http://localhost:8000/render'
files = {'file': ('file.xlsx', open('template.xlsx', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')}
payload = {'context': json.dumps({'OUT': 'csv','SHORT': 'short'})}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload)
print(r.json())
```