# How to send optional parameters using HTML checkboxes when uploading file to FastAPI?

Tags: python, html, checkbox, fastapi

I would like to upload a file that is going to be analyzed with a package that can have multiple parameters. For instance, I would like to upload the audio file, and then check some optional parameters to analyze this audio. Here is an example of how the frontend should look like:

[image]

However, I don't quite understand how to implement this in the API. Can anyone please help me out?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class audiofILE(BaseModel):
    name : str
    speech : str
    music: str
    noise: str


app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="template")

@app.get('/home/{user_name}', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def write_home(request: Request, user_name: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("basic_form.html", {"request": request, "username": user_name})

@app.post("/submitform")
async def handle_form(assignment: str = Form(...), audioFile: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        seg = Segmenter()
        segmentation = seg(audioFile.filename)
        segmentation_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(segmentation, columns=['labels', 'start', 'stop'])
        if noise :
            result =
            return HTMLResponse(content=segmentation_1.to_html(), status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        return HTMLResponse(content={'message': str(e)}, status_code=400)
```

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Awesome Form</title>
        <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Super Realistic Form</h1>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="multiply_by_2" name="multiply_by_2" value="True">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request)

Comment: no it doesn't, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at **Method 1** of  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), which provides an example on how to submit both `Form` and `File` data together.

In your example, you have to make sure to include the [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) attribute (which specifies the URL that processes the form submission) in the HTML [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), as well as define the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#name)  attribute (which specifies the name of the [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element) using the **same** key/name you declared for the parameters in your endpoint. You can have the various parameters accompanying the audio file declared as `Optional` with `False` as the default value, and have the frontend send `True` only if they are selected by the user.

### Working Example:

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, File, UploadFile, Request
from typing import Optional
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')

@app.post('/submit')
def submit(
    speech: Optional[bool] = Form(False),
    music: Optional[bool] = Form(False),
    noise: Optional[bool] = Form(False),
    audio: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    if noise:
        print('Noise has been selected')
        
    return {'speech': speech, 'music': music, 'noise': noise, 'file': audio.filename}


@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="/submit"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="checkbox" id="speech" name="speech" value="True">
         <label for="speech">Speech</label><br>
         <input type="checkbox" id="music" name="music" value="True">
         <label for="music">Music</label><br>
         <input type="checkbox" id="noise" name="noise" value="True">
         <label for="noise">Noise</label><br><br>
         <label for="audio">Choose audio file</label>
         <input type="file" id="audio" name="audio" onchange="enableSubmitBtn();"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit" disabled>
      </form>
      <script>
         function enableSubmitBtn() {
            document.getElementById('submitBtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```