# Error {"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]} using FastAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, jinja2, fastapi

I am building an online store using python, jinja2 and FastAPI.
When I submit the form, to post add to cart data, I received an error

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}
```

In the swagger UI, the post route is functioning and posting to the postgres database. I used the pydantic model because I want the query parameter from the req.body and populated data on the index.html using jinja2 templating. I am using post to add the product to cart when running uvicorn the error in the console is INFO:     127.0.0.1:58872 - "POST /checkout HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity. I read that there could be issues with dict type vs json data but I dont see where I could change that if the data type is the source of the issue.

What could be causing these errors?

checkout.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter,Form, HTTPException, Depends, Request, Body
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse, RedirectResponse
from typing import Annotated
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates 
import models
from models import Products
from database import engine, SessionLocal
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from routers import checkout
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates


router = APIRouter()

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

#pydanitic request - can be utilized for the post method
class ProductRequest(BaseModel):

    product: str 
    price: int 

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

db_dependency = Annotated[Session, Depends(get_db)]

@router.get("/checkout")
async def display_all_checkout():
    return {"checkout": "items"}

@router.post("/checkout",status_code=201, response_class=ORJSONResponse)
async def addcheckout(db:db_dependency, request: Request, created_product: ProductRequest):
    
    try:
        product_product = request.form['product_product']
        product_price=int(request.form['product_price'])
        product= db.query(Products).filter(Products.id == id).first()
        if product_product and product_price and request.method == 'POST':
            DictItems=Products(**created_product.dict())
            print(DictItems)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        
        return RedirectResponse(url="/product" )
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', path='/products/css/base.css')}}">
    
</head>
<body class="grv-font">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="grv-text__heading--xxlarge">Store</h1>
        <h3 class="grv-text__heading--medium">Welcome to the store</h3>
    
        <div class="no-records">Your Cart is Empty</div>
    </div>
    <div class="shopping-cart">

    </div>

    <div class="grv-row">
       
            {% for product in product_list %}
         <div class="grv-col--xs-2 grv-col--md-4 grv-col--lg-6">    
            <div class="grid-fill">
                <form method="post" action="{{url_for('addcheckout')}}">
                    <br>
                
                  <div class="content grv-card">  
                
                        <span class="product-name">{{product.product}}</span>
                        <span class="product-price">${{product.price}}</span>
                    

                    <div id="add" class="add-to-cart">
                        <label for="product_id">product_id</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{{product.id}}"/>
                        <label for="product_product">product_id</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="product_product" name="product_product" value="{{product.product}}"/>
                        <label for="product_price">product_id</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="product_price" name="product_price" value="{{product.price}}"/>
                        

                        <input type="number" class="product-quantity" name="quantity" vlaue="1" min="1"/>
                        
                        <input type="submit" value="add to cart" class="grv-button--action grv-button--compact"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

</div>
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
        

    </div>
<script src="{{url_for('static', path='/products/js/index.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from database import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String



class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index= True)
    product=Column(String)
    price=Column(Integer)

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Comment: You might find related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804). If you would like to send `Form` data instead, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74515250/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74507628/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your POST request is expecting JSON data, but you're actually sending form data. So FastAPI is trying to parse the request body as JSON, and failing.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Accept form data instead of JSON. You can do this by changing the route to:

```py
@router.post("/checkout",status_code=201, response_class=ORJSONResponse)
async def addcheckout(db:db_dependency, request: Request):
```

Remove the `created_product: ProductRequest` argument. Then you can access the form data from `request.form`.

2. Continue accepting JSON, but actually send JSON from the frontend. You'll need to make your form submit JSON instead of regular form data.

So in summary, your options are:

1. Accept form data (remove the JSON argument)
2. Actually send JSON from the frontend to match what the endpoint is expecting.