# How to send a form with data and a File in Vuejs 3 and FastAPI?

Tags: python, vue.js, axios, fastapi, multipartform-data

I am trying to create a very simple form where I can send two fields, that they are `family_type_id` and  an image. The thing is when I try to send them, FastAPI displays an error saying this:

```
detail: 
   [{loc: ["query", "family_type_id"], msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}]
   0: 
    {loc: ["query", "family_type_id"], msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}
```

It says that I am not sending the family_type_id and the schema is blocking me, but it is not true because I am sending the data like this:

```
methods: {
  handleFileChange(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  },
  handleSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('family_type_id', this.familyTypeId);
    formData.append('support', this.file);

    // Usando vue-axios para enviar la solicitud
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/family_core_data/store', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
  },
```

I am sending the data with POST and I am using formData to append every single field and then sending all..  my schema in FastAPI is like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from fastapi import UploadFile
from typing import Union
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

class FamilyCoreDatum(BaseModel):
   family_type_id: int
```

My router is this one:

```
@family_core_data.post("/store")
def store(data: FamilyCoreDatum = Depends(), image: UploadFile = File(...)):
   data_received = data.dict()

    return {"message": data_received['family_type_id'], "image_filename": image.filename}
```

somebody could tell me what I am not seeing ? because I see that it's ok... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Depends()`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/), when declaring the `data` parameter (along with using `FamilyCoreDatum` Pydantic model as the type of it) in your endpoint, would render `data` to be expected as **query**, not form, data.

You should instead define [Form data](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) in your endpoint using `Form()` (see related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029319/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824288/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804)) or have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) for more options on how to upload both `File` and `Form`, or JSON, data in FastAPI. The following posts might also prove helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317758/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74507628/17865804).