# How to display drop down item based on other drop down field in Swagger UI using FastAPI?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I have this subset object (a list of dictionnary).

```
quiz = [
        {'question': 'Cassandra',
         'response': 'relationnelles', 
        },

        {'question': 'MongoDB et CouchDB',
         'response': 'oriented objet,
        },
 ]


my_question = tuple(q['question'] for q in quiz)
```

Here is the model

```
class Quiz(BaseModel):
    question: Literal[my_question]
    response: str


@api.post("/postdata")
def post_data(form_data: Quiz = Depends()):
    data.append(form_data)
    return data
```

I would like to get the response automatically linked when I select the question item.
The idea is to got the answer of the selected question dynamically
Here is the actual output I got.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you can do that using query parameters, but you could certainly have something similar using request body (see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#body-with-multiple-examples)). You can always implement your own frontend using [`Jinja2Templates`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/?h=templates#using-jinja2templates) and/or [`HTMLResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=htmlresponse#return-an-htmlresponse-directly). Examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804).