# How to post multiple form fields and files to a RESTful API using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, rest

Suppose we have the example RESTful app from [Method 1 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/) which takes string, float, boolean, and an arbitrary number of file inputs.

I cannot get Matlab's [`webwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html) to successfully post data to this API. It seems to only allow multiple form fields or data from a single file. Calling webwrite with a [`weboptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) argument is limited to a single key/value pair. I also tried argumenting the function call with multiple weboptions objects to provide each of the required fields, but that doesn't work either.

A workaround is to use a system call to `curl`. This will work for the example app linked above:

`system('curl -F name=foo -F point=0.13 -F is_accepted=false -F files=@test_files/a.txt -F files=@test_files/b.txt http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit');`

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this in Matlab?