# Send already base64 encoded string to app.get and decode inside the function creates corrupt file

Tags: python, base64, fastapi

```
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/prediction_api")
def make_prediction(file1: str):
    #decode base64 string data
    decoded_data=base64.b64decode(file1)
    #write the decoded data back to original format in  file

    filename ='image.jpg'
    image_result = open('Images\\'+filename, 'wb') 
    image_result.write(decoded_data)
```

This code creates a corrupt file. I want to send a base64 encoded image to this api and it will do some tasks and return 0 or 1. When I encode an image within in my local desktop and first reading then encoding then decoding it, it doesn't create a corrupt file but when I send already encoded image as string parameter it corruptly creates. What is wrong with this?

Note: "file1" parameter is the base64 encoded version of the image. I am trying to pass it as:
after http part /prediction_api?file1=base64encode then enter.

Comment: In addition to the links above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) as well.

Comment: I could not understand those solutions.  I tried to convert them to Form but it didnt solve the problem. I mean why I cant send the base64string as argument why base64 decoder doesnt work with that?

Comment: What's the size of your request? Most browsers (and web servers as well) have a hard limit on the allowed length of a GET parameter, often limiting it to 8k/32k bytes. Have you tried using a POST-request with the file as a base64 encoded JSON field instead?

Comment: Yes it is over than 32k ,but I won't have the file in the project, only the base64 version of it will be receivedf from java web application. So this python api will be called from java web application . I cannot just create a string and put the base64 manually. I need to take it as parameter or another idk. :/

Comment: Is there any apigateway or webserver like nginx. Size of get request body size and size post request body size not might be same. Also did u try with java application? Are u sure base64 content is correct form.

Comment: You should not use the normal base64 for URL parameters, because the default base64 alphabet contains characters (like `+`), which have a specific meaning in URLs. You need to use base64url (or "URL and Filename safe Base64 Alphabet"); possibly that is causing the issue here (though I did not verify that).