# FastApi - upload files with other models fields

Tags: javascript, python, fastapi

I have a small project in FastApi and I want to upload a file along with the model. I have the following model (standard order):

```
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = "orders"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    is_shipped = Column(Boolean)
    filename = Column(String)
```

and basic pydantic schemas (for data validation):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class OrderBase(BaseModel):
    name: str


class OrderCreate(OrderBase):
    filename: str


class Order(OrderBase):
    id: int
    is_shipped: bool

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I also have two main routers, one for file uploads and one for order uploads. (Ideally I would like to keep two routers because it gives me more flexibility)

```
file_list = {}

@app.post("/upload-files/")
async def upload_files(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    file_ids = []
    for file in files:
        file_id = str(uuid4())
        file_ids.append(file_id)

        file_list[file_id] = file.filename
    return {"file_ids" : file_ids}

@app.post("/submit-form/")
async def submit_form(data: str = Form(...), file_ids: List[str] = Form(...)):
    return {"data" : data, "file_references" : [file_list[file_id] for file_id in file_ids if file_id in file_list]}
```

The main difficulty is that in order to load an order from attachments I must first contact one routers and then another. I would like to be able to do it all at once. How to achieve this?

What would a form look like where I could upload a model and a file at once?

I am trying to make that when loading sqlalchemy model the attachment file is loaded at the same time.

Comment: Both of your cases uses `Form` variables in your current version; is that your intention going forward as well? You can't combine using a JSON body and a `Form` file upload (i.e. regular file upload support), so you'd usually have to do this - but in that case, you can create an endpoint that accepts all three parameters, and then call common service functions in each endpoint to do the necessary tasks.

Comment: @MatsLindh I assumed that the input point on the frontend would be a single form whose fields are the fields of the Order model. I would be glad if you could give me an example of your last statement with the code

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: @Chris I will try, thx