# How to send image and text in a POST Request using FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

Hello I have written some code for a FastAPI endpoint. It is supposed to take in 3 parameters: name, template and file(this is the image). The image is stored in the project directory and the name and template is returned.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

app = FastAPI()

class Input(BaseModel):
    name: str
    template: str
    file: Optional[UploadFile] = None

@app.post("/test")
def upload(input: Input,file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()

    return (input.name, input.template)
```

Now I try to make a request to the endpoint. And I get this error message.

```
{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","input"],"msg":"Field required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"}]}
```

I try to send the data via json and the image separately when making the request but I am unsure why it is throwing this error. Here is the code where I make the request.

```
import requests
import json

# Define the URL of the FastAPI endpoint
url = 'http://localhost:8000/test'

# Define the input data for the request
data = {
    'name': 'Example',
    'template': 'template',
}
json_data = json.dumps(data)

file_path = 'templates/file.png'
files = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}

try:
    response = requests.post(url, json=json_data, files=files)

    # Print the response content
    print("Response:")
    print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: There is a relevant discussion here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is discussed in the discussion linked in the above comment that `UploadFile` uses `multipart/form-data` as the `content-type` so this does not play well with the JSON data encoded using Pydantic models.

Please also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request/70640522#70640522).

**Solution1**

One solution would be to pass the required parameters as query parameters to the API endpoint, here is an example:

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/test")
def upload(name: str, template: str, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(name, template)
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(file.filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()

    return (name, template)
```

Which can be called as follows:

```py
import requests
import json


# Define the input data for the request
data = {
    'name': 'Example',
    'template': 'template',
}
json_data = json.dumps(data)

file_path = 'file_test.jpg'
files = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}

# Define the URL of the FastAPI endpoint
url = f'http://localhost:8000/test?name={data["name"]}&template={data["template"]}'


try:
    response = requests.post(url, json=json_data, files=files)

    # Print the response content
    print("Response:")
    print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

And produces the following response:

```
Response:
["Example","template"]
```

**Solution 2**

As per @MatsLindh's comment, it is also possible to pass the parameters as form data, should you not wish to include them in the path. Here is an example:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Form, UploadFile
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/test")
def upload(
    name: Annotated[str, Form()],
    template: Annotated[str, Form()],
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
):
    print(name, template)
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(file.filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()

    return (name, template)
```

And called as:

```py
import requests
import json


# Define the input data for the request
data = {
    'name': 'Example',
    'template': 'template',
}

file_path = 'file_test.jpg'
files = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}

# Define the URL of the FastAPI endpoint
url = f'http://localhost:8000/test'


try:
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)

    # Print the response content
    print("Response:")
    print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Output:

```
Response:
["Example","template"]
```

Comment: You should generally be careful about supplying content in GET parameters as they usually end up in access logs; if you're going to supply each parameter and not use a model, why not define them  as `Form()` arguments and supply them as additional form fields?

Comment: This is also an option, and I would say preferable. I have updated the answer above to show an example using form data. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If an answer is already provided in an existing question, [please vote to close as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) instead, rather than copying fragments of that answer into similar posts.