# FastAPI / pydantic: field_validator not considered when using empty Depends()

Tags: python, dependency-injection, enums, fastapi, pydantic

I am following **Method 2** of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/1504082) to be able to upload multiple files in combination with additional data using fastapi. It is working fine.

After starting to implement the handling of the additional data including validation using pydantic's `BaseModel` i am facing an issue:

My custom `field_validator` is working when using the model class directly but it is not working as expected, when using it via FastAPI and `Depends()`.

The key point is that i want to use a python `Enum` and i want to be able to use the Enum's `names` in the additional data (query parameters). For this reason i am using a custom validator to only allow names which exist in the enum.

When i initialize the model manually, the validation works as expected:

```py
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator, ValidationInfo, ValidationError

class VehicleSubSystems(Enum):
    A = "A Verbose"
    B = "B Verbose"

class EvaluationArguments(BaseModel):
    vehicle_sub_system: VehicleSubSystems

    @field_validator("vehicle_sub_system", mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def validate_vehicle_sub_system(cls, vehicle_sub_system: str, _info: ValidationInfo) -> VehicleSubSystems:
        """ Allows using the enum names instead of the values """
        try:
            return VehicleSubSystems[vehicle_sub_system]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(f"Can not find vehicle subsystem '{vehicle_sub_system}'. "
                             f"Allowed values: {[e.name for e in VehicleSubSystems]}")

def test_validation_is_performed():
    """ Test that the validation is performed """
    EvaluationArguments(vehicle_sub_system="A")

    try:
        EvaluationArguments(vehicle_sub_system="DOES_NOT_EXIST")
    except ValidationError:
        print("Test passed")
    else:
        print("Test failed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_validation_is_performed()
    # prints "Test passed" as expected
```

Combining this with the FastAPI application shows unexpected behavior: The field_validator is not considered. Instead the default behavior of the model class is used.

Server code:

```py
import uvicorn
from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Depends, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

def create_args(vehicle_sub_system: str):
    return EvaluationArguments(vehicle_sub_system=vehicle_sub_system)

@app.post("/process-works")
def process_works(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...), eval_args: EvaluationArguments = Depends(create_args)):
    return f"Got {len(files)} files and {eval_args}"


@app.post("/process-fails")
def process_fails(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...), eval_args: EvaluationArguments = Depends()):
    return f"Got {len(files)} files and {eval_args}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Client code:

```py
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
    files = [('files', open('d:/temp/a.txt', 'rb')), ('files', open('d:/temp/b.txt', 'rb'))]
    params = {"vehicle_sub_system": "A"}

    print("Calling process-works")
    resp = requests.post(url=f"{url}/process-works", params=params, files=files)
    print(resp.json())

    print("Calling process-fails")
    resp = requests.post(url=f"{url}/process-fails", params=params, files=files)
    print(resp.json())

    # Output
    # Calling process-works
    # Got 2 files and vehicle_sub_system=<VehicleSubSystems.A: 'A Verbose'>
    # Calling process-fails
    # {'detail': [{'type': 'enum', 'loc': ['query', 'vehicle_sub_system'], 'msg': "Input should be 'A Verbose' or 'B Verbose'", 'input': 'A', 'ctx': {'expected': "'A Verbose' or 'B Verbose'"}}]}
```

The `process-works` endpoint shows the expected behavior but only when using a separate dependency `Depends(create_args)` which mimics the direct usage of the model class.

The `process-fails` endpoint (using `Depends()`) shows the issue. I would expect that `Depends()` is just making FastAPI to call the init method of the model class and uses the validation as expected. But somehow it just ignores it.

I could not figure out why, perhaps somebody can explain what happens here and if there is a solution without the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

`Depends(x)` will check `args` in `x`, and fill the arguments in. So you should pass `x` to `Depends` in this case.

ref: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/

---

If you don't like to write a `create_args` function, maybe you can use `Body()`.

ref: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/

---

- My Example

```py
# client

import requests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

    params = {'fff': 'A'}

    resp = requests.get(
        url=f"{url}/ggg/",
        params=params,
    )
    print(resp.json())

    resp = requests.post(
        url=f"{url}/ppp/",
        json=params,
    )
    print(resp.json())

'''
{'fff': 'A Verbose'}
{'fff': 'A Verbose'}
'''
```

```py
# server

from enum import Enum
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import field_validator


class EEE(Enum):
    A = 'A Verbose'
    B = 'B Verbose'


class MMM(BaseModel):
    fff: EEE

    @field_validator('fff', mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def fffvvv(cls, vvv: str):
        return EEE[vvv]

    @classmethod
    def model_validate_query(cls, fff):
        print(f'{fff = }')
        return cls(fff=fff)


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/ggg/')
async def ggg(qqq: Annotated[MMM, Depends(MMM.model_validate_query)]):
    print(f'{qqq = }')
    return qqq


@app.post('/ppp/')
async def ppp(bbb: MMM):
    print(f'{bbb = }')
    return bbb


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)


'''
INFO:     Started server process [15273]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
fff = 'A'
qqq = MMM(fff=<EEE.A: 'A Verbose'>)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50513 - "GET /ggg/?fff=A HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
bbb = MMM(fff=<EEE.A: 'A Verbose'>)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50514 - "POST /ppp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
'''
```

Comment: Can you explaing why simply using `Depends()` is not working? The class is initialized, but why the validator is not called? What is the difference to a normal class initialization. I cant find the explanation in the docs for that.

Comment: Its difficult to explain it in words for me, I'm not native English user. Sorry. I recommend you read the source code to figure it out if you really want to know how it works. btw you can read the `inspect` stdlib first if you haven't use it.