Why does my Python FastAPI server keep returning the status code of 422 when I test it using Pytest?
Here is my FastAPI code. For simplicity purposes, I have made the code to simply return the data passed to it:
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import storage
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List

cred_obj = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred_obj, {
    'databaseURL': '...' # Cannot reveal
})

class Item(BaseModel):
    req: str
    username: Optional[str] = None
    project_name: Optional[str] = None
    task_name: Optional[str] = None
    task_desc: Optional[str] = None
    task_status: Optional[str] = None
    task_priority: Optional[str] = None
    task_due_date: Optional[str] = None
    task_assignee: Optional[List[str]] = None
    task_assigner: Optional[str] = None
    task_attachment: Optional[str] = None

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/items/")
async def handlereq(item: Item, file: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None)):
    return item


FastAPI testclient is used to test the code in a separate code _test.py:
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app
client = TestClient(app)
def test_handlereq():
    response = client.post("/items/", json={"req": "login", "username": "XXXX", "password": "XXXX"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"req": "login", "username": "XXXX", "password": "XXXX"}


I ran the server and the test in split terminals:
The server can successfully run but the terminal /item/ returns status code 422
How can I fix the code so that it returns status code 200 and the json is able to be processed?
I tried python request before to post request to the server, but it returned that my data was an unprocessable entity.

I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request
