Why does FastAPI response with Validation Error when requesting a schema with files?
I have a route to which I need to send a request in MyRequest scheme, as well as a list of files:
@router.post("/myEndpoint", response_model=MyResponse)
async def my_endpoint(my_request: MyRequest,
                      db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    ...

class MyRequest(BaseModel):
    userId: str
    language: str
    files: list[UploadFile] = File(...)

But when I make a request, I get a ValidationError:
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
      "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
  ]
}

I tried to remove files from the schema, passing them as an argument along with it:
@router.post("/myEndpoint", response_model=MyResponse)
async def my_endpoint(my_request: MyRequest,
                      files: list[UploadFile] = File(...),
                      db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    ...

class MyRequest(BaseModel):
    userId: str
    language: str

But there was no effect:
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "my_request"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
      "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
  ]
}


You didn't include your request and I guess you've swapped your two controller definitions (as you mention removing UploadFile, but you've added it now), but there's two issues: 1) you can't combine a JSON body and UploadFile, and 2) in your second request, you're not sending a proper JSON body as part of your request - exactly why that is the case is impossible for anyone else to say without seeing an actual curl/requests example of what request you're sending.

You can find a list of suggested ways to work around 1) in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request
