# How to use an endpoint with multiple body params and fileupload in FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, fastapi

I have an application that stores files and  additional information e.g. author, comments DB. I can pass an file to FastAPI, but getting issue by passing it together with parameters.

I checked following question [How to add multiple body params with fileupload in FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232908/how-to-add-multiple-body-params-with-fileupload-in-fastapi) and this issue [[QUESTION] Use UploadFile in Pydantic model #657](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/657)  but without success.

I tried 2 definitions in the FastAPI endpoint

**Option 1**

```
class Properties(BaseModel):
   language: Optional[str] = None
   author: Optional[str] = None

@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def uploadfile(params: Properties, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    #internal logic
```

**Option 2**

```
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def uploadfile(file: UploadFile = File(...),
                         language: str = Form(...),
                         author: Optional[str] = Form(None)):
   #internal logic
```

**Client code**:
Following code is used on client side, but response is **422 Unprocessable Entity** for both options.

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
     response = requests.post('http://localhost:8005/uploadfile/', data={'language':'en', 
     'author':'me'}, files={'file': f})
```

Both options can't be tested from swagger, there I am getting response: **value is not a valid dict**. Data looks good for me, but maybe I am missing something.

It seems that the client code is wrong, but also there I tried several changes without success.

In advance, thanks for your support!

**Solution that works for me**

As 'Drdilyor' wrote in his comment I have use option 2, as we are sending file. My issue was within order of arguments. After changing them everything starts working.

Comment: I tried passing `data={'params': ''}` and it somehow returned 200

Comment: this doesn't worked for me. However your comment helped me to think about the issue from another angle. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2257), In my opinion it is an HTTP limitation, we have to either use `application/json` or `multipart/formdata`, but not both. And since we are uploading files, `multipart/formdata` has to be used. This code (somehow) works:

```py
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def uploadfile(author: Optional[str] = Form(...),
                     language: Optional[str] = Form(...),
                     file: UploadFile = File(...)):
```

I tested it with
`curl http://localhost:8000/uploadfile/ -X POST -F author=me -F language=en -F file=@/path/to/file`, not sure about `requests`

You could also use query params as well i think

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I added information to my post. Client code that I was using initially is working now with Option 2. Issue was in the order of the arguments.